# Can I infer the template from a route helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When using `new_user_path` for example, can I infer the rendered template name from this helper alone?

I am using rspec's [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/example-groups/shared-examples), and looking for a way to assert that the rendered template is the correct one (rather than, say, a redirect) by only passing the route helper into the shared example.

i.e. what should `???` be if I only pass the `path` in?

```
shared_examples 'my spec' do
  it 'will not redirect' do
    get path

    expect(response).to render_template(???)
  end
end

Rspec.describe 'MySpec' do
  it_behaves_like 'my spec' do
    let(:path) { new_user_path }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a controller shared example, you can use the following:

```rb
shared_examples 'my spec' do
  it 'will not redirect' do
    get path

    expect(response).to render_template(request.params['action'])
  end
end

Rspec.describe 'MySpec' do
  it_behaves_like 'my spec' do
    let(:path) { new_user_path }
  end
end
```

In the context of your user controller, the test will be:

```rb
  it 'will not redirect' do
    get new_user_path # => get '/users/new'

    expect(response).to render_template('new')
  end
```

RSpec's `render_template` [matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/render-template-matcher#render-template-with-three-possible-options) only needs the action.